# java multithreading template benchmarking

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to benchmark different ways of multithreading a simple java application that transforms each element of an iterator into another.

Which of the below ways (java 8 parallel streams, regular multi-threading with lambda operator) is the most efficient? Based on the below output, it seems parallel streams is as good as traditional multi-threading, am I right?

The output for the below code (you have to replace alice.txt with another file) is:

> 153407    30420
>
> time in ms - 4826
>
> 153407    30420
>
> time in ms - 37908
>
> 153407    30420
>
> time in ms - 37947
>
> 153407    30420
>
> time in ms - 4839

```
public class ParallelProcessingExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(
            Paths.get("impatient/code/ch2/alice.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(contents.split("[\\P{L}]+"));

    long t=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Stream<String> wordStream = words.parallelStream().map(x->process(x));
    String[] out0=wordStream.toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(String.join("-", out0).length()+"\t"+out0.length);
    System.out.println("time in ms - "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-t));

    t=System.currentTimeMillis();
    wordStream = words.stream().map(x->process(x));
    String[] out1=wordStream.toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(String.join("-", out1).length()+"\t"+out1.length);
    System.out.println("time in ms - "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-t));


    t=System.currentTimeMillis();
    String[] out2=new String[words.size()];
    for(int j=0;j<words.size();j++){
        out2[j]=process(words.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println(String.join("-", out2).length()+"\t"+out2.length);
    System.out.println("time in ms - "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-t));

    t=System.currentTimeMillis();
    int n = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    String[] out3=new String[words.size()];
    try {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int from=i*words.size()/n;
            int to=(i+1)*words.size()/n;
            pool.submit(() -> {
                for(int j=from;j<to;j++){
                    out3[j]=process(words.get(j));
                }
            });
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(String.join("-", out3).length()+"\t"+out3.length);
    System.out.println("time in ms - "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-t));

}

private static String process(String x) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);
        //Thread.sleep(1);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return x.toUpperCase();
}

}
```

Comment: This might do better on [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com), given that it's asking about optimizing performance characteristics, not building functionality.

Comment: One problem you have is that the performance side is already down the sink; you fail to account for the JIT.

Comment: @Nathan, Placed it on code review as well. But the error question might be relevant here.

Comment: @fge, I don't follow. Are you talking about the exception error or the performance issue?

Comment: The performance issue. The JIT will only kick in on some piece of code after a certain amount of executions; you don't account for that at all. This is why tools such as jmh or caliper exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 parallel streams can be (in general!) as good as manual multithreading, but it also depends on the concrete situation.

You get RejectedExecutionException because you shut down the pool too early: you should call pool.shutdown() outside the for loop

One big advantage of Java 8 parallel streams is that you don't have to worry about such things.